# git every single file from github

Tags: git, github

When I type this command it only pulls two files that are up to date or "last committed". I want it to pull every thing from the repository because I deleted my working directory locally and I need to git everything back not just the last ones I changed.

```
 $ git pull origin master
```

Comment: Thank you. I got this errorerror: pathspec '-' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '-' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: did you delete your working directory, or did you delete your .git directory ?

Comment: my working directory but thanks anyways Answer #1 worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout master` should rebuild your working directory.

Comment: or even `git reset --hard HEAD` - `git checkout` might complain about unstaged changes or merge conflicts or several other things...